# Importing table onto cytoskape, imports headings but not data

Tags: cytoscape

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxMI.png)

I import my metadata table from the cytoscape directory downloaded from GNPS.
The data shows up in the next window under the appropriate headings.
But when I click import and then go to select a node in my network, the information does not show up in the node table at the bottom.

I have added screenshots for clarity.

Thank you anyone who can help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more information. Did you run your own code to import the data? If so, then please show it to us

Answer (score 0):

Also asked and answered on BioStars:

> Typically, this happens when there is a mismatch between the "Key Column for Networks", which you have set to "shared name" and the column in your spreadsheet to use to match it. I don't see what column you've selected to match the shared name column, but the values in those columns have to match in order to import the data.
>
> -- scooter

-- scooter